# How does the use_pty sudoers option prevent a persistence attack?

Tags: security, sudo, configuration, pty, hardening

As a rule in the Debian 10 hardening guide, [and various other audit guides](https://www.tenable.com/audits/items/CIS_CentOS_8_Server_v1.0.1_L1.audit:463b39e9e80bfdeeddaa1358afcd24ea) of the Center for Internet Security (CIS), setting the `use_pty` sudoers option is recommended for the following rationale:

> Attackers can run a malicious program using sudo which would fork a background process that remains even when the main program has finished executing.

In the `sudoers` man page, it is described that running a background process that retains access to the user's terminal after the main process has finished executing is no longer possible when the commands are run in a separate pseudo-terminal.

I don't really grasp the nuance here.
What does it mean to run the sudo command in a *separate pseudo-terminal*, and why is the background process attack no longer possible when this flag is set?

What other ramifications does setting `use_pty` have?

Thank you!